# Understanding the following sum

Tags: summation, continuity

I don't understand the following argument:

Let's observe the following sum:

$$\sum_{n \geq 4}\frac{n}{3}[3(1-x)]^n$$

Why we have that this sum is a continuous decreasing function of $x \in (\frac{2}{3},1]$? Obviously this sum vanishes in $x = 1$. Why can we now conclude that there exists $x_0 < 1$ such that the above expression is strictly less than $1$ for $x > x_0$?

Many thanks for some help!

Answer (score 1):

We can find a representation as rational function.
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{n\geq 4}}\color{blue}{\frac{n}{3}\left(3(1-x)\right)^n}
&=(1-x)\sum_{n\geq 4}n\left(3(1-x)\right)^{n-1}\\
&=\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)(1-x)\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n\geq 4}\left(3(1-x)\right)^n\\
&=\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)(1-x)\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{3^4(1-x)^4}{1-3(1-x))}\right)\tag{1}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{27(1-x)^4\left(x-\frac{5}{9}\right)}{\left(x-\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2}}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
The representation (2) reveals an asymptotic at $x=\frac{2}{3}$ and a zero at $x\in\left\{\frac{5}{9},1\right\}$. A *[curve sketching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_sketching)* can now be used to show that the function is continuously decreasing in $\left(\frac{2}{3},1\right]$.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we factor out $3^4(1-x)^4$ from the sum and apply the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.